# cube appears bright white when trying to do volumetrics

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

been trying to create some fog by using a volumetric cube, although keeps appearing as what is seen in the image below

[image: the example]

Comment: You have emission on

Answer (score 0):

As @AllenSimpson said, your emission is turned on, or rather too high. If you want it to be completely dark, set it to *0*, but if you still want some glow, use some small value.